# how to i can change wagtail cms page tag before save

Tags: python, django, wagtail

How can I change wagtail page tag before saving?

I can change the title by overriding `save()` like this-

```
class ProductPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey('product.ProductPage',related_name='tagged_items')

class ProductPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(BodyStreamBlock)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=ProductPageTag, blank=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.title = "my title" # work
      self.tags = "test,test2,test3" #not work
      super(ProductPage, self).save()
```

but I don't know how to change the tag list.

Comment: Could you show the complete Page and Tag class please?

Comment: ok , i added to the question

Comment: If you want to do anything before of save a object, you can use `signals` for your case could be `presave` check out doc of django  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save

Comment: thanks, But my problem is not change anything
i know hot to change title or publish date or other char or  Integer field but i dont know how to change tag 
tag is not char or Integer  
sorry for my bad english

Comment: @dentemm  ,juliansalas
i just want to find special words in body and add words to tag.

it's very important  please help me

Comment: i found the answer
i added to the question

Comment: Glad you found it!

Comment: Can you add it as an actual answer as well? Then we can upvote it!

Comment: @FlipperPA ok :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I Found the Answer** :D

just need  change

```
self.tags = "test,test2,test3"
```

to

```
self.tags.add('test',"test2","test3")
```

final code

```
class ProductPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object =ParentalKey('product.ProductPage',related_name='tagged_items')

class ProductPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(BodyStreamBlock)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=ProductPageTag, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.title = "my title" # work
      self.tags.add('test',"test2","test3") #work
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

(Or, when working with the old Python 2.7, `super(ProductPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`)